# alguien sabe que podria producir este error SqlExeption Incorrect syntax near "="

Tags: c#, sql

hola buenaas tengo una duda alguien sabria como podria solucionar este problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo unico que intento es verificar si en una tabla se encuentra un id repetido entonces lo que ago es verificar si el dato que intento ingresar ya existe y si existe en base a eso retorno algo para saber si existe o no pero pasa esto
ya e intentado hacer las consultas de muchas formas diferentes pero si no es con el = me tira error con () si no es eso me tira error con el and
pero cuando pruebo la consulta en el sql antes de pasarla a c# funciona bien entonces nose que pasa en el c# para que me tira ese error

```
string consulta = "SELECT r.IdSede 
FROM Reserva r INNER JOIN CupoSede cs ON r.IdSede = cs.IdSede 
and r.IdCliente =" + idCliente;
```

ya lo intente de varias formas pero de verdad que no llego al problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inténtalo con el `WHERE`

```
string consulta = "SELECT r.IdSede 
FROM Reserva r INNER JOIN CupoSede cs ON r.IdSede = cs.IdSede 
WHERE r.IdCliente =" + idCliente;
```

Entiendo que en la tabla IdCliente es un entero pero en el código está definido como un string. Si idCliente está definido como un entero deberías pasarlo as string:

```
string consulta = "SELECT r.IdSede 
FROM Reserva r INNER JOIN CupoSede cs ON r.IdSede = cs.IdSede 
WHERE r.IdCliente =" + idCliente.ToString();
```

Aunque de todas formas asegúrate que en el código `idCliente` tenga algún valor y no venga como una cadena vacía en tiempo de ejecución, esto podría provocar el error.

Comment: te podria hacer otra consulta esto es algo que se  puede hacer

Comment: SELECT r.IdSede FROM Reserva r INNER JOIN AfiliacionSede afs ON afs.IdSede = r.IdSede where r.IdCliente = +idCliente+ and r.IdSede = +idValidar;

Comment: osea yo podria hacer una consulta donde le concatene dos variables en la consulta de sql, y no solo una ?

Comment: Puedes concatenar dos o más variables, simpre y cuando la sentencia resultante de la contatenación sea correcta, desde el punto de vista de SQL.

Comment: a ok muchas gracias, tu respuesta me sirvio mucho, que tengas buen dia